# Depuis, dès, lors ou désormais ?

Tags: indications-de-temps

J'ai un peu de difficulté à comprendre la différence d'utilisation de `depuis`, `dès`, `lors`, `dès lors` et `désormais`.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut expliquer ces nuances ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- *[Depuis](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/depuis)* : période ayant débuté au moment indiqué et, sauf indication contraire, se poursuivant jusqu'au présent. (*for*, *since*, *from*...)
- *[Dès](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A8s)* : insiste sur l'instant précis où quelque chose a débuté ou changé (*from*, *as soon as*)
- *[Lors](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lors)* : ne s'emploie presque plus seul. (*Lors, vous n'aurez servante oyant telle nouvelle*, Ronsard, *Sonnets pour Hélène*, 1578). À partir de ce moment (alors, *then*) ou simultanéité de deux événements (*while*, *during*) : lorsque.
- *Dès lors que* : comme *dès*. (*once*)
- *[Depuis](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/depuis) lors* : depuis ce moment là (*since then*)
- *[Désormais](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sormais)* : ça n'a pas toujours été le cas (*nowadays*), à partir de maintenant (*from now on*), à partir de ce moment là (*from that time on*).

Comment: Merci! Et sauf `désormais` tous les autres peuvent être utilise dans le passé?

Comment: *Désormais* peut aussi être utilisé dans le passé: *Il découvrit la maison de la rue Plumet et s'y blottit. **Il était désormais** en possession du nom d'Ultime Fauchelevent.* Victor Hugo, Les Misérables.

Answer (score 2):

1. **depuis** This word (preposition), basically "*since*", is used to set a limit from which an action or a state of affairs can be specified. It is used for specifying those time limits in *the past*.

   - Il ne pleut plus **depuis** un momnent.
   - Le travail manque déjà **depuis** quelques temps.
   - Il n'allaient plus à l'école **depuis** longtemps.
2. **dès** This word (also a preposition) is also used to set a limit after which an action or a state of afffairs can be specified. It is used, however, for specifying limits both in the past and the present.  It corresponds to "*since*", "*from*" and some  locutions such as "*as early as*".

   - **Dès** son réveil il se ruait vers la cuisine et le réfrigérateur.
   - Vous ferez cela **dès** votre retour l'année prochaine
3. **lors** More specifically, as a word in the family given (depuis, dès, lors,…) this is the prepositional locution "**lors de**". This locution is used when there is a need to mention a state of affairs or that an action is taking place in a given period (that period is always is made expressed by a noun placed after "lors de" and is not explicitly the name of a period but the name of something with which is associated a period). It is used for periods both in the past and the present. In English it corresponds to "*while*", "*during*", "*for*".

   - **Lors des** jeux olympiques il y a eu beaucoup d'étrangers dans la ville.
   - Les enfants le feront **lors de** leurs prochaines vacances.

One must take care in using it not to transgress usage; whereas you'd say normally to your neighbour in English "Last year, for Christmas,  we had snow." you wouldn't say "Lors de Noël l'année dernière il y a eu de la neige."; it is a rather literary term.

4. **dès lors**  This locution is used  to introduce a limit after which will take place an action or a state of affairs will be true. It has the same meaning as "*from that point on*" but you can use it for limits in the past or a hypothetical time in the future. This is first a *preposition* used with nouns (depuis le temps/moment de);  it is used with verbs also (depuis ce temps/moment là); it is then an *adverbial locution*. This term also is rather literary. In every day speech, it is better to use sometning such as "**à partir de ce moment là**".

   - Les épidémies s'étaient succédées sans que l'on puisse faire beaucoup pour soulager les victimes ; **dès lors** les antibiotiques furent découverts les choses changèrent radicalement.
   - L'avis de certaines personnes fut prompt : **dès lors** vous aurez nettoyé vos appentis des débris de nourriture qui les jonchent, le nombre des rats diminuera.
   - (TLFi) **Dès lors** elle imita toutes les pratiques de Virginie.
5. **désormais** As another word to specify a limit in time "désormais" is used for spécifications in the past and in the présent. However, it's an adverb, not a preposition ; it isn't used to modify nouns, only verbs. It means "*from that point on*" in the past, "*from now on*" in the present.

   - Il avaient protégé leurs arrières et **désormais** il n'avaient plus rien à craindre.
   - **Désormais** nous nous entourerons de gardes armés pendant nos heures de travail.